# weakly null sequence and a weakly Cauchy sequence

Tags: functional-analysis

1. What does a weakly null sequence relate to a weakly Cauchy sequence? What did two sequence have properties ?
2. Let $(y_n)$ be a normalized and be a $\ell^+_1$ - sequence. Assume that there are positive scalar $(b_n)$ so that $(1 + {b_n})\left\| {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{b_i}{y_i}} } \right\| = \left\| {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n + 1} {{b_i}{y_i}} } \right\| < 1 $.
   Why did series $\sum\limits_n {{b_n}{y_n}}$ converge?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please consider adding your thoughts on the problems to your post so we can help you where you are stuck.

Comment: question 1: I wonder that a weakly null sequence may be a weakly Cauchy sequence, may not it? With quention 2, I didn't understand reason to series $\sum\limits_n {{b_n}{y_n}}$ converge.